# next-focus direction in recycleView widget

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, focus

When create simple recyclerView containing just two editText widgets, direction of next focus element when typing data is like on pic1 --- how to set direction of next focus element like that on pic2? 
cheers

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

my simple code

```
 <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_left"
        tools:hint="editTextLeft"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <EditText        
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_right"
        tools:hint="editTextRight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this use  `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` to move focus to the next Editext

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_left"
    tools:hint="editTextLeft"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

make your layout like this

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_left"
        tools:hint="editTextLeft"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <EditText        
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_right"
        tools:hint="editTextRight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```